# Creating Sub-Objects in Python

Tags: python, class, object, self, subobject

I need to create an object and define another object's property with that object.

For example, create a class called `Income`. Then with an `Income` object,  define in a class called `taxReturn` an attribute called `Income`.

That way, it'd be possible to access elements of a business's income by doing the following: `taxReturn.Income.sal_wge`. So far I have this:

```
class taxReturn:

    def __init__(self, income = None):

        income = income or ['sal_wge', 'intr_rec', 'txexem_intinc', 'divid_AGI', 'qual_divid', 'stinc_txref', 'alimony_rec', 
                 'bus_netprof', 'net_capgain', 'capgain_dist', 'othr_gain', 'IRA_dist', 'pens_annu_rec', 'pens_annu_AGI', 
                 'sch_E_netinc', 'sch_F_netprof', 'unem_comp', 'soc_sec']

        self.income = 'income'

class Income:
   def ('income'):
```

Comment: OK. So, what is your question?

Comment: How do I create a sub object that becomes an attribute to the larger object?

Comment: Same way as any other attribute. Where specifically are you having problems?

Comment: Alex, Would you spend a minute in drawing a class as rectangle and put the members in it? A simple picture or ASCII art will help us though.

Comment: you can have a class as an attribute of another class, same way you can have any variable as an attribute

Comment: Can I just do this? @DanielRoseman

Comment: No of course not, that's not valid Python syntax. But I thought your question was about how to make Income an attribute of Taxreturn, not how to define Income.

Comment: Sorry, I made the intended update in the above window. Yes, that was my question.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be some code left out in your example, but it's quiet straight forward to create sub-objects, you just instantiate them and assign to a member. Something like:

```
class Income:
    def __init__(self, sal_wge):
         self.sal_wge = sal_wge

class TaxReturn:
    def __init__(self, income = None):
         self.income = income or Income(sal_wge = 0)

t = TaxReturn()

print(t.income.sal_wge)
```

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I have a question though. I want income to be the sub object of TaxReturn. Don't you have it the other way around in this example? @skyking